# In VBA, how to express the cell formula in Sheet1 by the actual cell names from other sheets

Tags: vba, excel-formula

In Sheet1, the formula in A1 cell is expressed as    `=Sheet2!E1+Sheet3!F1+Sheet4!G1`,
the actual cell names of E1 in Sheet2, F1 in Sheet3 and G1 in Sheet4 are SourceFromSheet2, SourceFromSheet3 and SourceFromSheet4 respectively. Is there a setting or code such that the A1 cell formula in Sheet1 will ***automatically*** appear as `=SourceFromSheet2+SourceFromSheet3+SourceFromSheet4`

> [Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTudB.png) [Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZeRh.png) [Sheet3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcWff.png) [Sheet4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UInPl.png)

Comment: Yes, if you define the names with *workbook scope* they're accessible from anywhere in the workbook. If you defined the names with *worksheet scope* then they're only accessible from within the sheet that defines them.

Comment: I defined the names in sheets 2, 3 and 4 with workbook scope. They are named as SourceFromSheet2, SourceFromSheet3 and SourceFromSheet4 respectively. But the formula in cell A1 in Sheet 1 is still expressed as =Sheet2!E1+Sheet3!F1+Sheet4!G1. Can we automatically set it to =SourceFromSheet2+SourceFromSheet3+SourceFromSheet4?

Comment: No, you need to edit the formula to get that - could be achievable by inspecting each cell's `Precedents` collection and comparing to each name's `RefersToRange`, and then accordingly replacing the fragments in the formula. Now that's quite a lot of problems to solve for a single question, but tackle each problem one at a time and you'll get there; feel free to ask a specific question about a specific problem you're stumped with, embedding your code in the post and describing any errors you're getting. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Go in Sheet2, cell E1; the *name box* says "E1":

[image: cell E1 is selected, name box says 'E1']

Now type the name you want for it in the name box:

[image: cell E1 is selected, name box says 'testname']

Bring up the *Name Manager* from the *Formula* Ribbon tab:

[image: name manager showing workbook-scoped name 'testname' referring to Sheet1!E1]

Note the 'Scope' column says "Workbook": you can reference that name in any formula anywhere in this workbook!

Alternatively, create the name from the *Name Manager* itself; click the "New..." button and define the name in "Workbook" scope:

[image: New Name dialog definining 'AnotherName' referring to Sheet2!F2]

Now the workbook-scoped names appear in formula auto-completion and you know you've done it right:

[image: entering '=testname+Ano' in a cell shows 'AnotherName' in the autocompletion dropdown]

You can also programmatically define workbook-scoped names by adding to the `ThisWorkbook.Names` collection.